# Enable hardware (GPU) video decode acceleration with ffmpeg C API?

Tags: c, windows, ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration

I am using `avcodec_decode_video2()` to decode a particular video without enabling any GPU hardware support.

While I tried to get the hardware decoder by name:

```
mVideoCodec = avcodec_find_decoder_by_name("h264_dxva2");
```

But its results `mVideoCodec = NULL` although while running ffmpeg from command prompt using dxva2 hwaccel, no error is being shown. Here I am giving the configuration output what I got from the command prompt. can anyone please tell me how can I enable hardware acceleration properly while using `avcodec_decode_video2()` API to decode the video in C.

I am using a laptop with an NVIDIA GPU.

Log from command prompt:

> C:\ffmpeg\bin>ffmpeg -hwaccel dxva2 -i 9.mp4 -r 60 -vsync 0 -f image2 image-%2d.png**
>   configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx

Comment: What does `ffmpeg.exe -hwaccels` output?

Comment: @genpfault, the output showing like this, Hardware acceleration methods:
d3d11va
dxva2
qsv
cuvid

Comment: Welp, time to edit in a [mcve] then.

Comment: @genpfault I couldn't get it completely. can u please explain in a little bit more detailed way.